# Allow only system keyboard for iOS text field

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uitextfield, textfield

Is it possible to allow only iOS system keyboard for `TextField` in SwiftUI (or maybe for `UITextField` from `UIKit`)?

[There is a solution in Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW1) to reject the use of all custom keyboards but it's for the whole app and I need just for a single `TextField`.
[Screenshot from Apple docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJMnn.png)

Also iOS system keyboard is automatically used for secure entries, but it's just a plain `TextField` in my case.